# `select * from table where cloumn(varchar) =0` selects all data

Tags: mysql

everybody, I find a strange performance when excuting select query on MySQL 5.7 , which is really confused.

my table(MySQL 5.7)

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE name=0
```

result

```
+------+--------+--------------------+-------+---------+
|   id | name   | payment_password   |   age |   phone |  
|------|--------|--------------------|-------|---------|  
|    1 | test1  |                    |    22 |   12345 |  
|    2 | test2  |                    |    15 |   12345 |  
|    3 | test3  |                    |    11 |   12345 |  
|    4 | test4  |                    |    11 |   12345 |  
+------+--------+--------------------+-------+---------+
```

Can anybody explain why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as MySQL is concerned, a string that doesn't start with a number converted to an integer is 0. Try this:

```
SELECT CAST('test1' AS UNSIGNED), 'test1' = 0
```

Output:

```
0    1
```

The second output value of `1` indicates that MySQL thinks that `'test1'=0`. But if your string starts with a number, MySQL will convert the string to that number e.g.

```
SELECT CAST('45test' AS UNSIGNED), '45test' = 45
```

Output

```
45   1
```

Again, the second output value of `1` indicates that MySQL thinks that `'45test'=45`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of implicit type conversion. When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

In your case, when you are using `WHERE name=0` MySQL might be seeing arithmetic operation in the WHERE clause because `name` is of `varchar` type and performing implicit conversion to integers in that column.

You can find more detail [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) on MySQL type conversion.

[**Look Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3a502/7)

Comment: Don't thank us, rather follow [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)